# Please help me pick one of the following logos for my concrete resurfacing business (designed by me - a newbie)

Tags: logo

Please help me choose one of the following logos:
[image]

What we do is decorating concrete surfaces to give them different beautiful designs. We are not regular, concrete pouring contractors.

I designed all of the logos, so I realize they will all seem bad to most of you. Still, please help me choose the strongest one. Also, I'd greatly appreciate it if you have any quick tips regarding improving the most appropriate logo.

Comment: I'd like to see a larger version of #2, with some "dirt" added to that center rectangle instead of a monochrome fill – more concrete-ey. (I do need to let "boring concrete" sink in. You may accidentally be referring to another part of the industry.)

Comment: @usr2564301 Thanks for your input. I like your idea about about changing the rectangle, what do you think about something like - https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/subtle-concrete/ ? Also, I'm not sure what you mean by the bracketed part of your comment. Are you saying that I should go with a logo that has the slogan "We make boring concrete beautiful" in order not to be confused with regular concrete contractors?

Comment: That background looks great, just what I imagined. About the slogan: I am not a native speaker of English so I am wondering if one could read "We make *boring concrete* beautiful" as "We make it an an art to drill into concrete". It may just be me because I tend to see the p(h)un in things. Lots of my English writing vocabulary comes straight out of reading Douglas Adams and Terry Pratchett...

Comment: But for something to be a pun, a word that has two different meanings must be used. What we do is decorate concrete by applying a thin coating of a concrete overlay, epoxy paint, or acid stain. The actual decorative process is similar to painting in a sense. We spread or spray a substance onto a concrete floor either with a squeegee or with a hopper gun (respectively). I know Michael Connely has a novel called "Concrete Blonde" but I don't think that has anything to do with the slogan in the logo. Also, that's literally the shortest description of what we do, and it uses an alliteration

Comment: @usr2564301 but do you think perhaps dropping the word boring will be better?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the "strongest" of the 4..... then #1. But I'm not certain any of them, as they are, are suitable.

1. The upward angle of the trowel is a good thing. The color variations
   are decent. Type could be addressed a bit better - leading a bit
   tighter, and font weight reduced possibly, or two separate weights -
   one for each word. The swash is pretty bad. I'd rework that quite a
   bit.
2. The indents and lowered contrast make this one a no-go for me. They both
   *detract* from readability. The cut ins for the background appear to be an attempt to be visually creative but, for me, they fail and are for more of a distraction and hurdle than improvement. If it was just a white block behind the type, then maybe. More of a "label" design may work. You don't need to *force* visual intricacy if it's not natural.
3. This is merely uninspired without much imagination. We all know a
   trowel is used in concrete work. The type is too tightly kerned.
   It's just not good.
4. This looks like an oar in a box. The *last* thing I'd see is a trowel or
   "concrete" without reading the words. In addition, the scale of the
   larger letters and symbol compared to the full name is too drastic.
   Upon reduction the name is minuscule and difficult to read.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response. The one concern I have about number one is that it's too wide, which means I won't be able to use it as it is on social media. Would you recommend only using the trowel for avatars? Is that considered a bad thing to do, as it's slightly inconsistent?

Comment: Hi @JohnHolliday to be blunt.. I wouldn't use any of these, but you asked for the "strongest of the 4". So, that's what I stuck to. All I can state is that designing a *logo* to work with some *specific* usage typically means the logo isn't well designed. A good logo should work well for 99.99% of uses.